# Why can't we partition the quantum-mechanical phase space into discrete cells?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Near the bottom of page 2 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.2133.pdf), von Neumann states that not only is it impossible to simultaneously measure $x$ and $p$, but also that it is impossible to partition the quantum-mechanical phase space such that, with certainty, $x$ lies in interval $I$ and $p$ lies in interval $J$. This is impossible even if $|I| |J|>>\hbar/2$. My question is about the explanation of this fact, in footnote 5 (using the Fourier transform of the wavefunction).

If $\psi(x)$ vanishes outside $I$ (i.e., $x\in I$ with certainty) then $$0 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{c(p)\exp(i p x_0) dp}$$ For $x_0$ not in $I$, where $c(p)$ is the Fourier-transformed, momentum-space wavefunction. Why must the $c(p)$ become nonzero again and again for arbitrarily large values of $p$, as stated in the paper? Why is there no interval $J$ such that, with certainty, $p\in J$, that is, $c(p_0)=0$ for $p_0$ not in $J$?

It might be mathematically trivial, but I just don't immediately see how this fact follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question turns up in signal processing, and actually appears in the corresponding section of the [Uncertainty Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Signal_processing) Wikipedia page

> a function cannot be both time limited and band limited (a function
>   and its Fourier transform cannot both have bounded domain)

as well as having a more precise statement

> a function and its Fourier transform cannot both have finite support

along with a proof on the [Bandlimiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandlimiting#Bandlimited_versus_timelimited) page.

A less formal argument is that the original wavefunction may be expressed as $\psi(x)W(x)$ where $W(x)$ is a rectangular window function (equal to unity for $x\in I$ and zero outside), and therefore the Fourier transform must be a convolution of the Fourier transforms $c(p)$ and a sinc function of the form $\dfrac{\sin kp}{kp}$ where $k$ is some constant. Since the latter has infinite bandwidth in $p$, the convolution must also have infinite bandwidth.

Comment: I see it now- appreciate your response.